# how to autoplay a music using audio tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

i want to autoplay a mp3 file in jquery

i used this code,

```
function musicStart() {
  pop = window.open('', 'back__music', 'width=100,height=100', true);
  pop.document.write('<audio controls autoplay loop><source 
  src="./music.mp3"/></audio>');
}
```

loop is working,
but autoplay isnt.

when i added `autoplay="true"` or `autoplay="1"` or `autoplay="autoplay"` to audio tag, the results were the same.

or when i used embed tag, it doesn't repeatedly play the music.

i don't care using audio tag or embed tag

how can i do?

Comment: You could maybe try to trigger playback by calling the node's play method on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the solution !

I solved this way, if there is anyone that has the problem like me, follow me.

First, enter the link here~ [chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy](http://chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy), and Check from Default to **No user gesture is required**

after then, change your code like this

```
function musicStart() {
    pop = window.open('', 'back__music', 'width=100,height=100', true);
    if (back__music.location.href === 'about:blank') {
        pop.document.write('<audio controls autoplay loop><source src="./music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/></audio>');
    }
}
```

I wish hope with you :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('audio')[0].play();` (assuming you only have one `audio` in your page) should do the job.

A basic example:

```js
$('audio')[0].play();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls>
<source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4" type='audio/mp4'></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can achieve this as:

```js
$('.music').html('<audio controls autoplay> <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4"  type="audio/mpeg"> </audio>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="music">

</div>
```